# SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION between a line and a polygon returns what?

Tags: oracle, spatial, geometry

I'm confused as to what exactly the SDO_GEOM.SDO_INTERSECTION returns in Oracle. Documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/GUID-6191E200-BFBF-4D97-A9B2-92846DBF7175.htm#SPATL1118), but only gives examples of two intersecting polygons.

What if I have many lines, some of them are contained fully within the polygon and some intersect the polygon. Assume that I need the geometry of any line fully contained within the polygon (i.e. same as SDO_CONTAINS) AND the geometry of those parts of intersecting lines, which are inside the polygon.

Example image below. Assume I only need the geometries of the red lines, but not the green ones. Will SDO_INTERSECTION return all of the red ones or only those red ones, which also go outside of the polygon and have some green bits?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered this question for me and it is as I suspected.
SDO_INTERSECTION will return any lines fully contained within a polygon, as well as those parts of intersecting lines, which are within the polygon.
In other words, it will return the geometry of everything in red in the example image.